# ¿Cual es la mejor manera de checkear si una lista está vacía?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ejemplo de lista vacía:

```
a = []
```

¿Como checkear si está o no vacía?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opción 1:**

```
if not a:
  print("La lista está vacía")
```

**Opción 2:**

```
if len(a) == 0:
    print("La lista está vacía")
```